# ERROR: failed to solve: error from sender: context canceled

Tags: python, docker, build, pycharm, editor

docker build image, which failed to solve: error from sender: context canceled
Error occurs when compiling image in pycharm terminal, but there is no problem when pycharm is closed. I found that pycharm locks the files to be compiled, which causes docker to have no permission to access them. Eventually, I discovered that the files in the current directory, including the internal .idea files in pycharm, were compiled, making docker unable to access them. Finally, I added .idea to .dockerignore and the problem was solved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPbGC.png)

Engaging in active discussions with fellow internet users can be helpful in finding solutions to problems.

Comment: "Finally, I added .idea to .dockerignore and the problem was solved." - 
Thank you! That solved it for me too.